# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'staty', when trying to import resorces

Tags: resources

This error is showing no module named 'staty' when importing resources, & I've installed resources package too.

```
import resources
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you try to use django import-export Model Resource.
If so. You have imported wrong package. You should import like this
`from import_export import resources`